# How to store alphabets in localstorage instead of clickcount in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating some dynamic control and I wish to assign Id to it from local storage. Its working fine but instead of new number i wish to assign Alphabet (eg A,B) to newly created control. Is it possible to achieve it through javascript?

```
function nextNumber() {
  if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    Increment = localStorage.clickcount;

  } else {

  }
}

elem.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "ID " + Increment)//assigning id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non verified example how could you do it:

```
function nextNumber() {
  if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      var indx = localStorage.clickcount.charCodeAt(0) - 65; // Get ascii value from char
      localStorage.clickcount = String.fromCharCode(indx + 1);
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = "A"; // "A" has ascii value 65
    }
    Increment = localStorage.clickcount;

  } else {

  }
}

elem.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "ID " + Increment) //assigning id
```

Basically you should utilize numbers from 65 up (those are representing ASCII values of chars starting from A). Having that in mind, when you store initial counter it should point to "A" so it's 65. When increment you should convert back that character to ASCII value, increment it by 1 and convert back to character.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something using the alphabet letters and use [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) function like this:

```
let alphab="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
function nextNumber() {
  if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    Increment = localStorage.clickcount;

  } else {

  }
}

elem.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "ID " + alphab.charAt(Increment))//assigning id
```

But this is limited to the alphab length. You need to create a new function for such control.